# Create deb file for django

Tags: django, linux, package, deb

I have a Django app that I have to install it on customer server.

I want to made a `.deb` package for this app, and add my custom repo, then on my customer server, get it like `apt-get install {PACKAGE_NAME}` .

my questions:

A- is there any better solution?

B- how can I create a .deb package file for Django app?

I Read about making packages but I am more confused